# Resulting amplitude

Tags: trigonometry

We have to find the resulting amplitude A' and the phase of the vibrations 
[image]

I know one method to expand all the cosine terms then add add.

But I want to know is there any other good method to solve it.

Comment: Try using complex numbers. Instead of expanding cosines it will reduce to much simpler vectors

Comment: @RazimanT.V. Can you explain it how ?

Comment: Write $cos(\omega t + \phi)$ as $\rm{real} \exp(i\omega t + \phi)$. You can use this to factor out the $\exp(i\omega t)$ and work with the phases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using compound angle formulas, the expression is equivalent to $$\frac{3A}{4}\cos\omega t-\frac{3A}{8}\sin\omega t=\frac 38A\sqrt{5}\cos(\omega t+\epsilon)$$

From which you can deduce the amplitude and period.